# Angular / Typescript display list from object in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 7 and I am displaying some data.

Here are the parts:

```
myData: any;
```

The content of myData is:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Name 1",
    "stuff" : [ 
        {
            "cmd" : "something here"
        }, 
        {
            "cmd" : "something else here"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then is my app.component.html I have:

```
<ul class="code-editor-options-menu" *ngFor="let dat of myData">
  <li>
    <span>{{dat.name}}</span>
    <span aria-hidden="true">{{dat.stuff.cmd}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With this: `{{dat.stuff.cmd}}` I'm trying to list all of the items inside stuff.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your `myData`? Is it a single JSON as you shown or is it actually an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is not part of stuff, so you cannot iterate

check this snippet: [your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ug7xmn)

component:

```
  myData = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "stuff": [
      {
        "cmd": "something here"
      },
      {
        "cmd": "something else here"
      }
    ]
  }
```

view:

```
<ul class="code-editor-options-menu" *ngFor="let dat of myData.stuff">
  <li>
    <span>{{myData.name}}</span>
    <span aria-hidden="true">{{dat.cmd}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```